# Vector inequality regarding p-Laplace euations

Tags: analysis, inequality, partial-differential-equations, functional-inequalities

In chapter~12, (p.99) of [this note](https://jyx.jyu.fi/bitstream/handle/123456789/54658/Lindqvistplaplacenotes.pdf?sequence=1) it is written that

"In the case $p \geq 2$, the inequality
$$|b|^p \geq |a|^p + p<|a|^{p−2}a, b − a> + C(p)|b − a|^p$$
holds with a constant $C(p) > 0$. The case $1 < p < 2$ requires a modification of the
last term."

My question is what is exactly the inequality for the case $1 < p < 2$, what about the case $p=1$?
Thank you in advance